# WEKA: Can i combine two machine learning trained models into one model?

Tags: weka

I want to merge two machine learning models which are trained with two different data sets. How can I merge those two models into one instead of building a model by combining those two data sets using weka java library?

Usage: I'm splitting my whole data set (12 million) across the cluster and building individual models (to decrease the training time). So I want to get finally one single model by combining those all models. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple classifiers by [Vote](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.html) classifier.

If you want to code it yourself do something like:

```
double prediction1 = classifier1.classifyInstance(ins);
double prediction2 = classifier2.classifyInstance(ins);

// use your logic for combining predictions
double combinedPrediction = combinePredictions(prediction1, prediction2);
```

Also check https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-ensemble-machine-learning-algorithms-weka/